# Extract value from AsyncEither - ScalaZ

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future, scalaz, concurrent.futures

I am new in ScalaZ and in Scala in general so I faced the issue below. 
I wrote some unit tests for my application and what I need is to extract the value of the actual response.

May you have any hint on how I can do it?

```
Expected :PaymentResponse(7bc2dc3b-c347-422f-b204-ccefb22708fa,
                          7bc2dc3b-c347-422f-b204-ccefb22708fa,USD,15.9,PAYMENT_PENDING,Paypal,VISA,None)
Actual   :\/-(EitherT(Future(Success(\/-(PaymentResponse(7bc2dc3b-c347-422f-b204-ccefb22708fa,
               7bc2dc3b-c347-422f-b204-ccefb22708fa,
               USD,15.9,PAYMENT_PENDING,Paypal,VISA,None))))))
```

The whole test:

```
"should return a payment object" in {
  val paymentId = UUID.randomUUID()
  val a: AsyncEither[FinanceGatewayError, PaymentResponse] = paymentService.getPayment(ProfileId("profileId"), paymentId.toString)

  val expectedPaymentResponse = PaymentResponse(
    paymentId = paymentId.toString,
    orderId = paymentId.toString,
    currency = "USD",
    amount = 15.90,
    status = PAYMENT_PENDING,
    paymentMethodLabel = "Paypal",
    paymentMethodIssuer = VISA,
    threeDSecure = None
  )
  \/-(paymentService.getPayment(ProfileId("profileId"), paymentId.toString)) shouldBe expectedPaymentResponse
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you wrap your expected response into `\/-(EitherT(Future(Success(\/-(...)`?

Comment: No, that's not an option.

Comment: Can you provide your import statements and class definitions? I'm having trouble figuring out which library e.g. `AsyncEither` comes from.

Comment: @Astrid you don't need the `val a = ...`, it seems, because it is not used anywhere.

Comment: @Astrid I just added an answer with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this is the correct approach that I have.

```
"should return a payment object" in {
  val paymentId = UUID.randomUUID()
  val expectedPaymentResponse = PaymentResponse(
    paymentId = paymentId.toString,
    orderId = paymentId.toString,
    currency = "USD",
    amount = 15.90,
    status = PAYMENT_PENDING,
    paymentMethodLabel = "Paypal",
    paymentMethodIssuer = VISA,
    threeDSecure = None
  )
  val paymentResponse: AsyncEither[FinanceGatewayError, PaymentResponse] =
    paymentService.getPayment(ProfileId("profileId"), paymentId.toString)
  Await
    .result(paymentResponse.run, 5 seconds)
    .fold(
      error => fail(s"The test is failed because $error ."),
      payment => payment shouldBe expectedPaymentResponse
    )
}
```

Comment: FYI, I wouldn't recommend using `Await.result` because it blocks the thread. Scalatest has a few options for working with `Future`s that can be run in parallel - I go through them in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210054/what-is-the-best-way-to-assert-for-a-scala-method-whose-return-type-is-futureun/51210572#51210572 .